# Aborted (core dump) when outputting trie.dot

Tags: c

I get this error when running my trie.o that is supposed to output a trie.dot file, so it only outputs one word instead of the whole dictionary. It gets the input from dictionary.txt. I cannot put my full code here as it`s a school assignment, that's why I tried to search where exactly the error occurs and I think it occcurs in this insert-function of my code.

In my search for the error I learned that this error usually has to do with the memory (especially malloc and free()) but I can't find the error in the code.

error

```
  *** Error in `./output.o': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb77b5470 ***
  ======= Backtrace: =========
 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x767e2)[0xb767c7e2]
 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77530)[0xb767d530]
 ./output.o[0x80487fd]
 ./output.o[0x804876e]
  /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0xb761f935]
 ./output.o[0x8048641]
  ======= Memory map: ========
 08048000-0804a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 922197     /home/jordy/Desktop/Practicum/output.o
 0804a000-0804b000 r--p 00001000 08:01 922197     /home/jordy/Desktop/Practicum/output.o
 0804b000-0804c000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 922197     /home/jordy/Desktop/Practicum/output.o
 09ee9000-09f0a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
 b75d6000-b75f1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394080     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
 b75f1000-b75f2000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 394080     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
 b75f2000-b75f3000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 394080     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
 b7605000-b7606000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 b7606000-b77b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394055     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
 b77b3000-b77b5000 r--p 001ad000 08:01 394055     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
 b77b5000-b77b6000 rw-p 001af000 08:01 394055     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
 b77b6000-b77b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 b77c9000-b77cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
 b77cd000-b77ce000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
 b77ce000-b77ee000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394031     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
 b77ee000-b77ef000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 394031     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
 b77ef000-b77f0000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 394031     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
 bfeb6000-bfed7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
 Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: It's difficult to debug this without seeing all the code that writes to a trie, but one thing to look at is your `free(trie -> value);` statement. `free` only works if its argument was previously allocated with `malloc`, `realloc`, or `calloc`. If `trie->value` is not set to any value, for example, that's likely where your `invalid pointer` error is.

Comment: Your `trie_insert` source code is different in the two excerpts.  `free(trie -> value); trie -> value = malloc(strlen(value) + 1); strcpy(trie -> value, value);` is likely to get a NULL pointer dereference in the `free` statement because `trie_alloc` sets `value` to NULL. In the full source code excerpt, `trie -> value = malloc(strlen(value) + 1); free(trie -> value); strcpy(trie -> value, value);` is going to copy a string into freed space, which will not end well. Can you post up-to-date code that gives you the error?

Comment: No idea? I have to get it ready in 40 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can tell,

```
int trie_is_valid_key(const char* key)
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<=sizeof(key)){
        if('a'<= key[i] && key[i] <= 'z'){
            i++;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

will always return 0 because you're going to encounter a NUL byte at some point. You
probably want

```
   while (i<strlen(key))
```

Since `trie_is_valid_key` always returns 0, `trie_insert` is always going to execute

```
free(trie -> value);
```

which likely will try to free a NULL pointer, resulting in an error message from `free`.
You probably want

```
if(trie->value) {
    free(trie->value);
}
```

but I'm not sure you'd ever encounter anything but a NULL pointer there, so check your algorithm to be sure you really want to replace an existing value in that trie node.

Also, is `TRIE_NB_CHILDREN` at least 26? If not, the program may write outside the bounds of the `trie->children` array, trashing `trie->value`.